# SyntaxError: EOL On MD5 Script

Tags: python, syntax, eol

I am having trouble executing this python command and it keeps flagging this specific line. I've read the other posts about EOL, but I can't seem to find an issue with the types of quotes used.

```
logfile = "/Volumes/AC_SMN/03_DIGITAL_12/MD5_CHECKSUM_REPORTS/Text_Files” + id + ".txt"
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: You've got a `”` character at the end of `...RTS/Text_Files”`, not a normal double quote `"` one.

Answer (score 1):

The quote character after Text_Files is incorrect.  You could try this:

```
logfile = "/Volumes/AC_SMN/03_DIGITAL_12/MD5_CHECKSUM_REPORTS/Text_Files" + id + ".txt"
```

However, I would recommend using the string formatting syntax instead:

```
logfile = "/Volumes/AC_SMN/03_DIGITAL_12/MD5_CHECKSUM_REPORTS/Text_Files{}.txt".format(id)
```

Also, your variable named id is shadowing the built-in id, so best practice is to use another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

you have used wrong quote at the end of `Text_Files” + id +`

```
logfile = "/Volumes/AC_SMN/03_DIGITAL_12/MD5_CHECKSUM_REPORTS/Text_Files” + id + ".txt"
```

instead use this (double quotes at the end of the string)

```
logfile = "/Volumes/AC_SMN/03_DIGITAL_12/MD5_CHECKSUM_REPORTS/Text_Files" + id + ".txt"
```

Comment: @Jordan If it solved your problem, please consider marking the answer and up-voting it.